# PHP - cropping image - 20px from top and bottom

Tags: php, imagick

I need to crop 20px from top and 20px from bottom.

Is it possible in PHP with Imagick?

Answer (score -1):

Yes its possible. Look into below code

```
function cropImage($imagePath, $startX, $startY, $width, $height)
{
    $imagick = new \Imagick(realpath($imagePath));
    $imagick->cropImage($width, $height, $startX, $startY);
    header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
    echo $imagick->getImageBlob();
}
```

Comment: Well, i already saw that, but i do not really know, how to use it, to crop 20px from top and 20px from bottom.

Comment: You can crop, your qus is not clear, you need cropped 20px + 20px image or total image expect 20px top and 20 px from the bottom.

Comment: Total image except 20px from top and 20px from bottom.